# Replacin values of a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
col1
01
1
02
2
03
3
00
0
```

How can I replace values in col1 to be like the expected output below:

Expected Output:

```
col1
1
1
2
2
3
3
0
0
```

Comment: please provide the input in a reproducible form, it is currently ambiguous (both regarding the type and blank values): `df.to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```py
df['col1']=[int(x) for x in df['col1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(int)
```